# How to convert the installation of eclipse from eclipse for java developer to eclipse for EE developers?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm starting to work with oracle database and I want to make a connection with eclipse. For this I need to use the IDE for EE developer. I know that the best way to do that is to uninstall and reinstall eclipse, but the problem is that I tried too much time to completely uninstall eclipse from Linux but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Install the corresponding [Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0) entry.